# How to group_concat based on where condition and show same data in a single div?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to show all transaction that occurs in a date( as like. 12-12-12, 15-9-20).

now it is showing each transaction in separate div. but I want to show all transaction that occurs same day in same div. As linke I have five transaction in 12-12-12.

```
mysql> select * from all_trans;
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| row_id | user_id | trans_date | debit      | credit       | other      |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|      1 |      30 | 2015-11-09 | vcvv#      | dfdsfsd#     | df+-       |
|      2 |      30 | 2015-11-09 | tertreter# | tferterte#   | gdfgdf+-   |
|      3 |      25 | 2012-12-12 | 2000#      | 200#         | dfsdfsd+   |
|      4 |      30 | 2015-11-16 | dffdfgd#   | dfsdfdsfds#  | fsdfsd+c   |
|      5 |      30 | 2015-11-16 | dffdfgd#   | dfsdfdsfds#  | fsdfsd+c   |
|      6 |      30 | 2015-11-16 | fdsfsd#    | dgdfg#fsdfsd | dfsd+      |
|      7 |      33 | 2015-11-16 | dfsdfds#   | dfgdfgfd#    | fdvgfdgdf+ |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

mysquery was:

```
select *, group_concat(trans_date) from all_trans where user_id=$user_id;
```

My Script:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $sql = " select *, group_concat(trans_date) from all_trans where user_id=$user_id;";
            $insert = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $row_result = mysqli_num_rows($insert);
            if($row_result > 0){
                    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($insert)) {
    ?>

    <div class="#">
            <ul>
                    <li>

                            <h4>
                            <?php echo '<b>'.$result['trans_date'].'</b>';
                            ?>

                            </h4>


                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="debit">
                                                    <h4> <b>Debit</b>
                                                    <div class="total-transaction">

                                                            <li> <?php echo $result['debit']; ?></li>

                                                    </div>
                                                    </h4>

                                            </div>

                                            </div> <!-- end col4 -->
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <div class="credit">
                                                            <h4>
                                                            <b>Credit</b>
                                                            <div class="total-transaction">
                                                                    <li><?php echo $result['credit']; ?></li>
                                                            </div>
                                                            </h4>

                                                    </div>

                                                    </div> <!-- end col4 -->
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">

                                                            <div class="other">
                                                                    <h4> <b>Other
                                                                    <span class="fl-left">
                                                                            <div class="view-button">
                                                                                    <form action="" method="POST" >
                                                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-update">Update</button>

                                                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                                                                    </form>

                                                                            </div>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    </b>
                                                                    <div class="total-transaction">

                                                                            <li> <?php echo $result['other']; ?></li>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    </h4>

                                                            </div>

                                                            </div> <!-- end col4 -->


                                                            </div> <!-- end row -->
```

but it is showing just a single transaction not all 5 transaction under a div.

I don't know what will be my query to show all transaction have same date in same div.

Any help will be kind for me.Thanks

Comment: Please do not link to your code, instead add it to the question. Isolate as much data as necessary to cut back on size.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select *, CONCAT(trans_date , ' ') from all_trans where user_id=$user_id;
```